# Why doesn't append(int i) work for StringBuilder in Java sometime?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I am using a for() loop to append integer to a `StringBuilder` in Java. But, it seems there is a limitation of how large the `integer` can be appended and the limitation is different from computer to computer. For instance, the result of the code below turns out just "abc"; but when variable "i" is set to 100, it works and print "abc01234567...". Can anybody please explain why it happens?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abc");
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i ++){
     sb.append(i);
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Which platform and Java version are you running on?

Comment: I am working on Windows Eclipse, using JavaSE 1.8. Please try to increase the variable "i" to 10000 or  large. It may be reproduced then.

Comment: In that case it looks like Eclipse problem, not Java. Try to print it to file instead of terminal. Also try to open that file later outside of Eclipse.

Comment: You are correct. It works when printing it to a file, and also I tried NetBeans and it works there too. Thank you for help.

Comment: This is a bug (IMO) in the Eclipse console.  You can work around it by selecting "Window > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console" and checking/selecting the "Fixed width console" checkbox, and setting the "Maximum character width" to a value appropriate for you.  Quite bizzarely, if you run your example code, bring up the preferences window, check the checkbox and click apply, all the output will magically appear.